# Can I have two angular.module calls to the same ng-app in two different files?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller, angularjs-module

I have an angular.js app that is declared with `ng-app="audioApp"` in the `<body>` tag of the html file.

If I have an `angular.module` call in one javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('audioApp', []);
```

Can I make another identical `angular.module` call in a different javascript file? My application is mysteriously breaking with this second `angular.module` call, so it seems I can not have this call twice.

Any suggestions to a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You need to omit the `, []` part.

```
var app = angular.module('audioApp');
```

That'll grab a reference to the module, rather than *redefine* it.

What I like to do is keep a `module.js` file, which comes before any files which depend on the module or extend it.

**audioApp.js**

```
var app = angular.module('audioApp', ['some', 'deps']);
```

**someDirective.js**

```
var app = angular.module('audioApp');

app.directive(...);
```

**someController.js**

```
var app = angular.module('audioApp');

app.controller();
```

Comment: that'd go in the **audioApp.js** file in my example